# What am I getting wrong Resizing Date Picker and TextView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In a nut shell.  I am trying to add constraints to resize a date picker and text view.  Without the text view the date picker does what I want it to do (move to the top and centred), I add the text view it as soon as I add any for of constraint, when I run it I get this.  What am I missing or getting wrong

[These are the constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4v1.jpg)

[This is what it look liked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMjY.jpg)

[But this is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAKRD.jpg)

Comment: Can you please show me UITextView Constraints?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify compatibility version but let's assume that it is iOS 14 since you want to use compact date picker.

You can change Preferred Style to `.compact` in storyboard to preview how it will look like.

[image]

But, ups...  now storyboard warns you that there is problem with your layout. More specifically, date picker doesn't know how heigh it should be.

[image]

There are several ways how to fix problem with ambiguous height of view. But for some reason, auto-layout doesn't work for this view until you manually set its height with height constraint.

[image]

---

### "Auto-layout" solution

But, there is also one "hacky" solution which I've just created. But to make it work we need to embed out views inside vertical `UIStackView` (ideally with center alignment)

[image]

and our date picker needs to have required vertical content hugging priority

[image]

Now start with creating custom subclass of `UIDatePicker` and specify its `intrinsicContentSize` to height of first subview of first subview (private hierarchy, but ‍♂️)...

[image]

So create this subclass and don't forget to set this subclass in storyboard.

```
final class CompactDatePicker: UIDatePicker {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard
            let compactDatePickerViewFrame = subviews.first?.subviews.first?.frame,
            compactDatePickerViewFrame.height != 0
        else { return super.intrinsicContentSize }
        return compactDatePickerViewFrame.size
    }

}
```

Note that I also set its width to this subview's width so it also works when you have for example date picker in vertical stack view with center alignment.

[image]

Now one more thing you have to do is to invalidate its intrinsic content size in view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    datePicker.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

I feel like that this new compact date picker is something which Apple should definitely change, but ...

Answer (score 2):

Apple provided two new date picker appearances (inline and compact), changed the default appearance to one of these new appearances (compact) and did not provide a way to select the old appearance (wheels) until a later iOS version (at 13.4 through `UIDatePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle`). But what is really causing your problem here is that Apple seemingly forgot to implement `intrinsicContentSize` for these new appearances which is a problem if your constraints fail at positively determining a height. Robert Dresler's answer is on the right track (trying to bring back a useful `intrinsicContentSize` implementation) but it relies on knowledge of the internal structure of these views. As such

- it only seems to work for compact date pickers (the assumption being that the first subview of the first subview provides the correct intrinsic content size)
- it can break at any time should apple decide to change the internal structure of these views.

Until Apple finally fixes theses controls I had great success with the following

```
class FixedDatePicker: UIDatePicker {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    
        let host = UIView()
        host.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        let probe = UIDatePicker()
        probe.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        probe.datePickerMode = self.datePickerMode
    
        if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
            probe.preferredDatePickerStyle = self.preferredDatePickerStyle
        }
            
        let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: host, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: probe, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: host, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: probe, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    
        let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: host, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: probe, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: host, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: probe, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    
        host.addSubview(probe)
        host.addConstraints([left, right, top, bottom])
    
        return host.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
}
```

Same idea as Robert (provide a better `intrinsicContentSize` implementation) only mine does not rely on any specific knowledge of the view's internal structure and uses `UIView.systemLayoutSizeFitting` to calculate a size.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you!